# How to make a list of all nodes of content type ABC on a site (not a sitemap)?

Tags: caching

I have a D8 website with about 100 landing pages for a Google Ads campaign.  All of my landing pages are of content type **landing page**.

I want to make sure that the cache is primed for these pages because Google penalizes the site ("below average landing page experience") if it takes too long to load.

It seems like the standard approach to doing this is to run **wget** over your sitemap: https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/xml-sitemap-and-cache-priming

But, the landing pages aren't in my sitemap because they are too similar to each other.  So, what should I do to get a list of the URLs of all of my landing pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use Views (d'oh!) to do this.

Just make a view of content type **landing page** showing *fields* and then add a *link to content* and check the box for *show URL as text*.